# Catching a ArithmeticException in RestController in SpringBoot 2.0.4.RELEASE

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.0.4.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I've created this class to manage the Exceptions:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    public RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler() {
        super();
    }


    // 500

    @ExceptionHandler({ NullPointerException.class, IllegalArgumentException.class, IllegalStateException.class, RuntimeException.class })
    /*500*/
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public BodyBuilder handleInternal(final RuntimeException ex, final WebRequest request) {
        logger.error("500 Status Code", ex);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

the method Handles the RuntimeException and ArithmeticException
extends RuntimeException.

To test it I've created this method ;

```
GetMapping(path = "/getUsers", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> testErrors(HttpServletRequest request) {

    double ss = 3 /0;

    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.findAll());

}
```

expecting that will only returns a `HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR`  but instead it returns"

```
{"timestamp":"2018-08-31T09:21:21.717+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"/ by zero","trace":"java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero\n\tat ...
```

With this method

```
 @ExceptionHandler({ NullPointerException.class, IllegalArgumentException.class, IllegalStateException.class, RuntimeException.class })
    /*500*/
    public BodyBuilder handleInternal(final RuntimeException ex, final WebRequest request) {
        logger.error("500 Status Code", ex);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

I have the full trace:  `{"timestamp":"2018-09-03T07:04:58.803+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"/ by zero","trace":"java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero\n\tat`

and with this one, I don't see anything in the console with curl:

```
 @ExceptionHandler({ NullPointerException.class, IllegalArgumentException.class, IllegalStateException.class, RuntimeException.class })
    /*500*/
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public void handleInternal(final RuntimeException ex, final WebRequest request) {
        logger.error("500 Status Code", ex);

    }
```

and this other one, also nothing in the console:

```
@ExceptionHandler({ NullPointerException.class, IllegalArgumentException.class, IllegalStateException.class, RuntimeException.class })
    /*500*/
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleInternal(final RuntimeException ex, final WebRequest request) {
        logger.error("500 Status Code", ex);


        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [piradian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1961033/piradian) didn't point it out specifically, but the problem seems to be the return type of your `handleInternal` method. In the code, which you have provided, the return type is `BodyBuilder` and you return the value returned by `ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)`. Actually, as the `BodyBuilder` name suggests, it represents an implementation of [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). What you should actually do in this case is this:

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
```

And change the return type of the method to `ResponseEntity` or `ResponseEntity<Object>` (the body is empty in your case, so there really is no big difference).

However, taking into account that there is no body returned in your example and you already have your method annotated with `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)`, all you could do is change the return type to `void` and not return anything - this is exactly what [piradian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1961033/piradian) suggested. This should work as well.

Comment: `@Poger` you absolutely right. But as you write: "taking into account that there is no body returned in your example and you already have your method annotated with @ResponseStatus" returning a value is redundant (annotation already declatively express the need) and little messy (e.g. the question arises - what heppen if annotation response status is different from returned one?).

Comment: I totally agree on that. All I wanted to do is to analyse the case step by step in order to explain what was the actual cause of the problem and how to fix and improve the code step by step. Perhaps I should have put more emphasis on the fact that using both annotation and returning a `ResponseEntity` at the same time might not be a good idea. Good point.

Comment: I can see the HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR using postman, not curls

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@ExceptionHandler({NullPointerException.class, IllegalArgumentException.class, IllegalStateException.class, RuntimeException.class})
/* 500 */
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public void handleInternal(final RuntimeException ex, final WebRequest request) {
    logger.error("500 Status Code", ex);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

> use this one

```
@RestControllerAdvice//insted of @ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {    
   @ExceptionHandler(value = { Exception.class, RuntimeException.class })
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public BodyBuilder handleInternal(final RuntimeException ex, final WebRequest request) {
        logger.error("500 Status Code", ex);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not fix the problem.